# A refreshless WordPress website

Tags: ajax

As I said in my previous post, I am totally new in the WordPress world. My knowledge of PHP, Css, HTML and JavaScript is a little old but I am sure I can do this by my own with some guidance.

Please consider the image below:

[image]

It consists of four main pages. By clicking on every category, new content will be loaded without the whole page getting refreshed every time.

Please help me. How should I do this in WordPress?

Loop functions, plugins, widget, even if you name your options, it would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is bit of a snag in your terminology - "responsive" nowadays primarily refers to sites that adapt to screen sizes and is mostly unrelated to dynamically loaded content.

WordPress is not natively engineered for Ajax themes. It is of course possible and people do create such, but as percentage of overall theme building in ecosystem it's tiny.

In a nutshell you will have to pick technology for implementation first and make it play with WordPress second.

The common starting point is general info [on using Ajax in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and you might or might not want to go with [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) framework which is included in WP core.